# Instantiate variables in class

Tags: c++, class, shunting-yard

I am busy with a shunting-yard algorithm. If you have an expression like:

```
x + y + sqrt 25 - 3
```

the class doesn't know what the variables name and value would be. So I have a function in the class, instantianteVariable(char name, int value), with the calls:

```
expr.instantiateVariable('x',5);//Set x = 5
expr.instantiateVariable('y',3);//Set y = 3
```

How can I substitute the unknown variables in the expression, with the now known variables?
x and y could be any character, so I can't create class members, with the names x and y.

Comment: How are you defining and evaluating the expression?  Is it a line of code, a string, or what?

Comment: The expression is in RPN, stored in a string. When I evaluate it, I tokenize it.

Comment: What is "*the class*"?

Comment: I just wrote my own class, with all the functions and members required, for the shunting algorithm.

Comment: And how is anyone supposed to know that? You ask the question as if your class was a well known thing.

Comment: Sorry man, didn't thaught it will cause confusion in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could create a map or dictionary for each variable required.  During the process of evaluating the expression, you use the map to look up "tokens" necessary.